# android program stops in silence

Tags: android, adapter, fragment

I'm trying to change content of my ListFragment extension, but some mysterious things happen.

In my MainActivity I have ToFragment and call:

```
ToFragment.changeContent(newContent);
```

This function looks like:

```
public class DataListFragment extends ListFragment {   
    CustomArrayAdapter mAdapter;
    public CustomArrayAdapter getAdapter() {
        return mAdapter;
    }
    @Override 
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setEmptyText("");
        mAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity());
    }
    public void changeContent(ArrayList<FinalData> data) {
        System.out.println("first");
        mAdapter.setData1(data);
        System.out.println("second");
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        setListShown(true);
    }
}
```

And, at last, setData1 function is:

```
public void setData1(ArrayList<FinalData> data) {
    System.out.println("third");
    clear();
    if (data != null) {
        for (FinalData appEntry : data) {
            add(appEntry);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my program, it calls changeContent() function, then it prints "first", but doesn't print "second" and "third". Then it just doesn't do anything! No exception, no program break...  It calls mAdapter.setData1(data); and disappears. Do you have any ideas?

UPD:
This is CustomArrayAdapter class:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FinalData> {
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void setData1(ArrayList<FinalData> data) {
        System.out.println("chch");
        clear();
        System.out.println("chch");
        if (data != null) {
            for (FinalData appEntry : data) {
                add(appEntry);
                System.out.println("chch");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        FinalData item = getItem(position);
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.train_info)).setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.train_info)).setSelected(true);
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.stations_info)).setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.stations_info)).setSelected(true);
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.stations_info)).setText(item.getFullData());
            ((AutoResizeTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.time_info)).setText(item.getShortData());
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.train_info)).setText(item.getTimeData());

            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.train_info)).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6dcaec"));
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.stations_info)).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#a8dff4"));
            ((AutoResizeTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.time_info)).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6dcaec"));
        } else {
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.train_info)).setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.train_info)).setSelected(true);
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.stations_info)).setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.stations_info)).setSelected(true);
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.stations_info)).setText(item.getFullData());
            ((AutoResizeTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.time_info)).setText(item.getShortData());
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.train_info)).setText(item.getTimeData());

            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.train_info)).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cf9fe7"));
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.stations_info)).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ddbcee"));
            ((AutoResizeTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.time_info)).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cf9fe7"));
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your CustomArrayAdapter code

Comment: Post little more detailed code. with error log.

Comment: The issue is that there are no errors!:)

Comment: Please post more code. E.g. the actual code where changecontent is called.

Comment: One of the reasons that app may be stopped by the system is the lack of memory but it is usually reflected in the logs.

Comment: what exactly code is necessary?